# Review and rating not visible in play store

Tags: android, google-play

One of my friend has submitted a review and a rating to my app on play store. He can see his review when visiting play store, I also got a notification that I received a review(via email and play console), but when I click on reply, an error message is shown as it was deleted. If I check my app on play store I do not see the review and the rating. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: maybe you should wait until review is public? It takes some time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

This app is not exist in your mobile so review does not display. because google trace this network.

Comment: If you don't have it installed, you can't write a review about it

Comment: After reviewing your app,please don't uninstall .This app keep in your mobile minimum 1/2 days. Because google algorithm is so many intelligent and trace your comment.

Comment: Ok, so it's been a day and nothing have changed. Is there any link I could report this problem? I think there is a problem with my package because the download counter in play console is also not displaying correctly the download number

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there are two reasons

1. You can’t leave a review from an enterprise account, like an account for work or school.
2. The content of that review is meaningless.

Things you can do is, Try from a personal Google account and try to review something meaningful.

[Check Google's document about app review](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)